# How to link 2 widget options dynamically in R Shiny?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I'm trying to link the two options `Type Selection` & `Subtype Selection` as shown in the image. So I expect if I click `Beer` under `Type Selection`, I wouldn't see `ICE WINE RED` in `Subtype Selection` as it isn't a subtype of beer. Any idea to link `Type Selection` & `Subtype Selection`, so everytime I check some types in `Type Selection`, I wouldn't see irrelated subtypes in `Subtype Selection`?

Not sure if you can see bcl dataset, if can't here is the data screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BDLG.png)

Here is my code for these 2 functions:

```
dput(head(bcl))

ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          sliderInput("priceInput", "Price", 0, 100, c(25, 40), pre = "$"),
     
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "type",
        label = "Type Selection:",
        choices = c("BEER" = "BEER", "WINE" = "WINE", "SPIRITS" = "SPIRITS", "REFRESHMENT" = "REFRESHMENT"),
        selected = c("BEER", "WINE")
      ),
    
      checkboxInput("filterSubType", "Filter by Subtype", FALSE),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.filterSubType",
        uiOutput("SubtypeSelectOutput")
      ),
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      br(), br(),
      #tableOutput("prices")
      DT::dataTableOutput("prices")
    )
  ) 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$SubtypeSelectOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("subtypeInput", "Subtype",
                sort(unique(bcl$Subtype)),
                selected = "ALMOND",
                multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  
   output$summaryText <- renderText({
     numOptions <- nrow(prices())
     if (is.null(numOptions)) {
       numOptions <- 0
     }
     paste0("We found ", numOptions, " options for you")
   })

   prices <- reactive({
     prices <- bcl
  

     if (is.null(input$subtypeInput)) {
       return(NULL)
     }

     
     prices <- dplyr::filter(prices, Type %in% input$type)
     
     if (input$filterSubType) {
       prices <- dplyr::filter(prices, Subtype == input$subtypeInput)
     }
     

     prices <- dplyr::filter(prices, Price >= input$priceInput[1],
                             Price <= input$priceInput[2]
                             )
  
  
     if(nrow(prices) == 0) {
       return(NULL)
     }
     prices
   })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(prices())) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    ggplot(prices(), aes(Alcohol_Content, fill = Type)) +
      geom_histogram(colour = "black") +
      theme_classic(20)
  })

  output$prices <- DT::renderDataTable({
    prices()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you add `bcl` data to make this a reproducible example? You can use `dput(head(bcl))` and edit your question with the result.

Comment: Thanks Ben, not sure if you can check the bcl data, but if not pls check the screenshot.

Comment: Instead of including the command `dput(head(bcl))` in your code, please run it in your console and paste the output here so we have a sample of your data to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `SubtypeSelectionOutput` so that it filters based on the first input.

```
output$SubtypeSelectOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("subtypeInput", "Subtype",
                choices = bcl %>%
                  filter(type %in% input$type) %>%
                  pull(Subtype) %>%
                  unique() %>% sort(),
                selected = "ALMOND",
                multiple = TRUE)
  })
```

This may not solve all of your issues with this app, but it will properly link `Type Selection` & `Subtype Selection`.